# applicationDidFinishLaunching not invoked on Console App

Tags: macos, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to write a simple command line app that can display some info on a notification. But, the Delegate is not being called, and neither is the Notification and I'm not sure what's missing here.

Judging from my output, I think the whole problem stems from the AppDelegate not being instantiated. But I am creating one just before I show call showNotification.

What am I missing here?

**src/main.swift**

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

var sema = DispatchSemaphore( value: 0 )

let server: String = "http://jsonip.com"
let port: String = "80"
let path: String = "/"
let todoEndpoint: String = server + ":" + port + path

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint)!

let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil {

        print(error!.localizedDescription)

    } else {

        do {

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
            {

                print(json)
                let ad = AppDelegate()
                ad.showNotification(title: "Title", subtitle: "SubTitle", informativeText: String(describing: json))
                sema.signal()

            }

        } catch {

            print("error in JSONSerialization")

        }

    }

})

print("Resume Task")
task.resume()

print("Wait for Semaphore")
sema.wait()
```

**src/AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: Notification) {
        NSUserNotificationCenter.default.delegate = self
        print("Delegate Self")
    }

    // NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate implementation
    private func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter!, didDeliverNotification notification: NSUserNotification!) {
        //implementation
    }

    private func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter!, didActivateNotification notification: NSUserNotification!) {
        //implementation
    }

    private func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter!, shouldPresentNotification notification: NSUserNotification!) -> Bool {
        //implementation
        return true
    }

    func showNotification(title: String, subtitle: String, informativeText: String) -> Void {
        let notification: NSUserNotification = NSUserNotification()
        print("Show Notification")
        notification.title = title
        notification.subtitle = subtitle
        notification.informativeText = informativeText
        //notification.contentImage = contentImage
        notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName
        NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)
        print(notification.isPresented)

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Resume Task
Wait for Semaphore
["about": /about, "reject-fascism":
Impeach Trump!, "ip": 110.50.73.141, "Pro!": http://getjsonip.com]
Show Notification
false
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: `URLSession` needs a run loop. A CLI doesn't have a runloop by default. And to display notifications you have to **run** the application. Instantiating `AppDelegate` is not sufficient.

Comment: command line apps don't use AppDelegate, https://www.raywenderlich.com/128039/command-line-programs-macos-tutorial

Comment: PS: And what is the semaphore waiting for??

Comment: I think I've gone about this 'quick first project' in completely the wrong way. The idea was to have a background app that monitored a server's json and displayed the results periodically in a notification. The semaphore was because I was advised to do that to prevent my app closing before URLSession was finished.

Comment: fyi: command line projects do use AppDelegate, just differently, via `NSApplication.shared.delegate = appDelegateVar`, then `NSApp.run()`